# nginx URL rewrites, applying wildcard

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting

I am using `nginx` to `rewrite` some urls. how would I take the wildcard part of the initial url and apply it to the destination url? 
**ex. ^/il-it/news /news** where news is its the wildcard and its auto applied to the destination.

```
rewrite  ^/il-it(/.*)?$ / permanent;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this -

```
rewrite  ^/il-it/(.+)/?$ /$1 permanent;
```

Comment: thank you... that worked. Can I ask why (.+) and not (.*) ?

Comment: `(.+)` - one or more, `(.*)` - Zero or more times